# Docker volume bind empty volume or convert files to folders

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm running a container by sending to docker daemon so it can run a sibling container and in that container I try to run another container and mount a volume to access some data, however in the sibling container, the volume is either empty or the file is converted to a folder...

Running the first container:

```js
$ docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it example /bin/bash

root@3aa35965846a:/home/node/example# ls some_volume/ 
test.txt
root@3aa35965846a:/home/node/example# cat some_volume/test.txt 
hello


// Running the second container
root@3aa35965846a:/home/node/example# docker run -v /home/node/example/some_volume/:/some_volume/ -it node:10 /bin/bash

root@6a84739fbb92:/# ls /some_volume/
*  test.txt
root@6a84739fbb92:/# cat /some_volume/test.txt/
cat: /some_volume/test.txt/: Is a directory
```

The first time I run the second container the volume is empty, if I try to mount a file directly it is converted to a folder, and after that if I try to mount the folder like the example above, there is only the file I tried to mount earlier and it is a folder.

How is this possible ? If i try to mount a volume outside the first container I don't have any problem, how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first path in the `docker run -v` option is always on the host system.  For example, if you

```
docker run -v /etc:/x busybox cat /x/shadow
```

it will dump out the *host's* encrypted password file, regardless of whether you ran this command directly from the host or from a container.

There isn't a way to share an arbitrary directory from one container to another.  If the launching container knows something about its own directory structure (in particular that some directory was mounted from a specific host path or named volume) then it can replicate that to the other container, but that's not a generic answer.  The other behaviors you're seeing are just a consequence of those directories not existing on the host system.

In general I would advise *not* using Docker for short-lived processes that principally interact with the outside world through the filesystem.  Take whatever program you'd run in the other container, install it in your image's `Dockerfile`, and run it directly without going through Docker.

If you really can't avoid this workflow, the only thing I've found to work reliably is to `docker create` the container, `docker cp` files in, `docker start` it, and `docker wait` for it to finish.  When it's done, `docker cp` the result out before `docker rm` it.  That's a kind of painstaking workflow but it gets around the problem of the two containers not sharing any filesystem space.

Comment: I have to use 2 containers so, is there a simpler way to share a folder between 2 containers ? Maybe if I create a named volume that I share with both I could write in it with one container and read in it with the second container ?

Comment: You _can_; the first container needs to know what the volume is named and where it's mounted.  As my answer hints you can't keep the first container from rooting the system, if it's malicious or if there are any sort of security issues at all (many SO questions that try to script this allow trivial shell-injection attacks, for example).